# Simplify a path containing ".."

Tags: linux, bash, files, filesystems

I'd like to simplify a path containing parent directory (`..`) references, but without making it absolute.

E.g., a path like `foo/bar/../baz` should be simplified to `foo/baz` since the `bar/..` part cancels out<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, this is not true if `bar` is a symlink somewhere else - but feel free to ignore this: I don't care if the simplification returns different results than the original path in the presence of symlinks.

Comment: `foo/bar/../baz` is not necessarily the same as `foo/baz` if `foo/bar` is a synlink.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I think I covered that well in the footnote, and I'm OK if there is a difference in that case. Is anything unclear in that note?

Comment: @roaima - no, because I do not want an absolute path.

Comment: @Networker - based on the question, no (I am explicitly asking for a _relative_ path as output and that question is explicitly about getting an _absolute_ path).

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you are looking for is `realpath`:

```
$ realpath --relative-to="$PWD" "foo/bar/../baz"
foo/baz
```

it also works fine with symlinks, use `-s` to ignore them:

> -s, --strip, --no-symlinks
>                 don't expand symlinks